# Url is not loading in iFrame

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe, cordova

i am trying to load url in iFrame and using **jQuery Mobile** tabs but it shows empty frame and url is not being loaded here is the html code

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one"><img src="faceBook.png" width="84" height="38"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#two"><img src="gplus.png"  width="84" height="38"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#three"><img src="linkedInn.png" width="84" height="38"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#four"><img src="tweeter.png" width="84" height="38"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <iframe id="facebookFrame"  height="100%" width="100%" src="http://m.facebook.com" > </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <iframe id="gplus"  height="100%" width="100%" src="https://plus.google.com" > </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <iframe id="linked"  height="100%" width="100%" src"https://touch.www.linkedin.com" > </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    <iframe id="tweet"  height="100%" width="100%" src="https://mobile.twitter.com" > </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
  <p>&copy;ABC</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Most social websites do not allow themselves to run in iFrames due to clickjacking. That is for sure true for facebook, twitter and googleplus...

Comment: so is there any other solution ? i don't want to them to open in phone browser, i want them to open in application so i can effectively use jquery tabs . . .

Comment: No, there is no solution to embed those site into another web site. They require a login if the user is not logged in already, and for that to be secure they forbid the browser to display them in any kind of external frame, to avoid phishing.

Comment: rather than iFrame what else i can use to achieve this ?

Comment: Look into using the site's API, RSS Feeds, and/or social network aggregation services.

Comment: @adilwaqar how important is that feature for you? I could imagine a very time and coding intensive workaround

Comment: @FelixLahmer  well my application is all about using multiple social networking sites simultaneously on one tap....

Comment: @adilwaqar the way I would go is using the Client url Library from PHP  http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php , do you think it matches for your purpose?

Comment: @FelixLahmer well i don't have any idea about it coz i never worked in php. i have found another solution by using Cordova InAppBrowser, what do you think which option is the best one ...?

Comment: @adilwaqar you can do many fancy stuff with Cordova and you surely will find a solution that matches your purpose, but the biggest downside i know so far, is that it is not as portable as it promises to be, probably you will have problems with portability from one device to the other device, the most problems occur with Blackberry, but who uses a blackberry, except my customers? :O So i think you will be fine, with less labor expense on ios and  android. I cant report about Windows Phones

Comment: @FelixLahmer i am developing only for android and iOS. so i think i should go for InAppBrowser , but thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: no problem, i will create an answer, covering some stuff we just discussed

Comment: Sure, i will happily mark it as accepted . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The given Facebook hack is not working anymore, it was solved 07/14

---

---

You are not able to place it in an IFrame because the page developers have forbidden you to do so.

As you can see here, when using the IOS developer Console

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

X-Frame-Options

```
DENY 
The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

SAMEORIGIN 
The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.
```

---

There are some possible timeintensive workarounds, like using [CURL (PHP.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as a proxy.

Using specific Hacks of the Social Networks, like [this](http://m-austin.com/blog/?p=19) one for Facebook, which are **NOT recommended**, due to legality and due to the fact that they are working on fixes, after which your Application/Website etc. will **NOT work anymore**.

Creating an Native Mobile application, with the downside that you have ZERO portability.

Creating an Mobile Application, that uses mostly the Webstandards (HTML, CSS, JQuery), for example [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) .

PRO

- Easy to style and setup

CONTRA

- Portability

---

The last one is what i would suggest, as long as you got a small amount of Operating systems, that need to be served.